# Azure RDP random disconnects

Tags: azure, rdp

Our users work on terminalserver on Azure VMs and we experience random disconnets througout the day.
We could make it ia bit more stable by configuring Keep alives, but we still have disconnects.
It simply disconnect some seconds and then reconnects fine Again.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) Check your local network Firewall is not blocking you. 
2) Have you looked at the event log on the Azure VM ? can you see events that correspond to you disconnects. 
3) Have you put any alert monitoring on the box. For example are you running out of memory or cpu.